# How to use QCoreApplication::postEvent to inject synthetic input events

Tags: c++, qt, qcoreapplication

I'm injecting Keyboard and Mouse events which are comming over the network into my Qt Application and use `QCoreApplication::postEvent` for this. The mouse coordinates are absolute screen pixel coordinates.

```
QMouseEvent *event = new QMouseEvent(type, QPoint(x, y), mouse_button, mouse_buttons,
    Qt::NoModifier);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(g_qtdraw.main.widget, event);
```

Initially I had just one widget (referenced by `g_qtdraw.main.widget`) so I simply used that one as the receiver argument for `postEvent`. Now my application has more than one widget and the above code does not do what I want any longer.

A second widget is shown in fullscreen mode and I know that all mouse events have to go to this window but with the above code they are still routed to the main widget.

How do I choose the correct widget as the receiver (the one under the mouse x,y coords)? Is there a standard way, so that Qt chooses the right widget or do I have to track this myself?

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you use [`QApplication::widgetAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#widgetAt) to find the correct widget at the position and then post to that?

```
QPoint pos(x, y);
QMouseEvent *event = new QMouseEvent(type, pos, mouse_button, mouse_buttons,  Qt::NoModifier);
QWidget *receiver = QApplication::widgetAt(pos);
QCoreApplication::postEvent(receiver, event);
```

I wouldn't expect that you would have to do this for the key events though.  They should be sent to the focused widget (`QApplication::focusWidget()`).

Unfortunately, I haven't tested any of this.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work using your hint. I also had to use receiver->mapFromGlobal(pos) in order for the coordinates to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest posting some code as according to the [documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent) the signature is:

```
void QCoreApplication::postEvent ( QObject * receiver, QEvent * event ) [static]
```

Have you tried giving a pointer to the corresponding `QObject` as the `receiver` argument?

(**edit:** note that `QWidget` inherits `QObject`)

Comment: I've added new info. When I have more than one window/widget, how do I choose the right one (the one under mouse x,y)?

Comment: Ah, you missed out the key information on how you wanted to decide the widget ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer that was added to the Question:

> I now use the following which works fine (Many thanks to [Dusty Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2174/dusty-campbell)):
>
> ```
> QPoint pos(x, y);
> QWidget *receiver = QApplication::widgetAt(pos);
> if (receiver) {
>     QMouseEvent *event = new QMouseEvent(type, receiver->mapFromGlobal(pos),
>         mouse_button, mouse_buttons, Qt::NoModifier);
>     QCoreApplication::postEvent(receiver, event);
> }
> ```

Comment: @trenki - If you add your answer as an Answer in a block, then please let me know so I can delete this. We still don't have a way to assign an answer to the OP for situations like these.