# QT QcoreApplication postEvent() behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, qcoreapplication

I have written this simple QT mainwindow, only if I pass QString argument to the QKeyEvent, it prints the key, I expect the key to be printed even without QString argument?

section 1 in below code does not seem to work (I don't get the key printed in the QLineEdit field; while section 2 works and "1" is printed! is this normal behavior? what happens to the event when its posted in first section of the code?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->ui->lineEdit->setFocus();

    Qt::Key key = Qt::Key_1;
    // 1
    QKeyEvent *event = new QKeyEvent (QEvent::KeyPress, key ,Qt::NoModifier); 
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(QWidget::focusWidget(), event); // Does not work! No key is set in the widget
    //
    //2 
    QKeyEvent *event2 = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, key, Qt::NoModifier, QKeySequence(key).toString());
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(QWidget::focusWidget(), event2); // this one works! 

}
```

Comment: I am observing similar behavior with keys and `sendEvent`. For example, `Key_Backspace` works, but `Key_A` does not. Also see [How to use QCoreApplication::postEvent to inject synthetic input events](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8729508/608639).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all key-events have a text representation (delete, curser movement, shortcuts, ...). For those who have one, the `QKeyEvent` class stores it in its text. You have to provide that text, otherwise its a "textless" event.

`QLineEdit` will just add the text, and not deduce it from the event type (as can be seen [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgetlinecontrol.cpp?h=dev#n1936))

Comment: Thanks @king_nak, I was confused cause in some SO threads people reported that it works for them! my perception of "It works" was that text is generated .. but now I have the full picture ..postEvent  works for both cases.